# Solving a first order BVP with two boundary conditions with scipy's solve_bvp

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am using scipy's BVP solver:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html

The problem I am running into is that you can only have as many boundary conditions as you have equations. I only have one equation but I have two boundary conditions. How can this be fixed?

**MWE**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
>>> 
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
>>> dydx = lambda x,y: y*np.sin(x)
>>> 
>>> result = solve_bvp(dydx, 
...     lambda ya,yb: np.array([ (ya[0]-1)**2 + (yb[0]-1)**2 ]),
...     x, [np.ones(len(x))], max_nodes=100000, tol=1e-9)
>>> 
>>> result
       message: 'The algorithm converged to the desired accuracy.'
         niter: 2
             p: None
 rms_residuals: array([  3.48054730e-10,   3.47134800e-10,   3.46220750e-10,
         3.45304147e-10,   3.44446495e-10,   3.43708535e-10,
         3.42834209e-10,   3.41730399e-10,   3.40902853e-10,
         3.40116511e-10,   3.39286663e-10,   3.38873550e-10,
         3.37853506e-10,   3.36632825e-10,   3.35880059e-10,
         3.35385717e-10,   3.35453551e-10,   3.34784891e-10,
         3.32401725e-10,   3.34486867e-10,   3.35674629e-10,
         3.37743169e-10,   3.34329677e-10,   3.29311236e-10,
         3.27606354e-10,   3.28578369e-10,   3.27772742e-10,
         3.26447666e-10,   3.24908674e-10,   3.24192402e-10,
         3.25862692e-10,   3.28872815e-10,   3.22757465e-10,
         3.21914926e-10,   3.20227078e-10,   3.23579897e-10,
         3.28140843e-10,   3.18151515e-10,   3.21177949e-10,
         3.16611117e-10,   3.45372059e-10,   3.18345626e-10,
         3.24069081e-10,   3.32570305e-10,   3.19141250e-10,
         3.14376144e-10,   3.18278959e-10,   3.11802424e-10,
         3.15597596e-10,   3.22818017e-10,   3.15384028e-10,
         3.17673241e-10,   3.08099021e-10,   3.11743210e-10,
         3.28763320e-10,   3.24475197e-10,   3.28343741e-10,
         3.25892534e-10,   3.12411478e-10,   3.37194926e-10,
         3.20060651e-10,   3.03517565e-10,   3.00795182e-10,
         3.06846379e-10,   3.00064770e-10,   3.05765788e-10,
         2.99543196e-10,   2.98157661e-10,   2.97863071e-10,
         2.96467397e-10,   3.74567928e-10,   3.24304178e-10,
         3.16165056e-10,   3.02449962e-10,   2.93348900e-10,
         3.08601600e-10,   2.93492038e-10,   3.11756310e-10,
         2.97438508e-10,   3.17903029e-10,   3.05491804e-10,
         3.02623385e-10,   3.06340149e-10,   2.94595579e-10,
         2.87571373e-10,   3.03866639e-10,   3.42985927e-10,
         3.21829601e-10,   3.70164964e-10,   3.53563487e-10,
         3.00178404e-10,   2.83888849e-10,   2.82310753e-10,
         2.85661232e-10,   3.11405296e-10,   2.80954237e-10,
         2.79523163e-10,   2.80819968e-10,   2.94406497e-10,
         3.19548071e-10,   2.95355340e-10,   2.77522541e-10,
         2.76703591e-10,   2.88121141e-10,   2.75290617e-10,
         2.84220379e-10,   2.89876300e-10,   3.14510031e-10,
         3.11057911e-10,   2.72303350e-10,   2.79168046e-10,
         2.90700062e-10,   2.78438999e-10,   2.68897634e-10,
         2.69286657e-10,   2.90472537e-10,   2.78378707e-10,
         2.97980086e-10,   2.97008148e-10,   2.65028623e-10,
         2.64744165e-10,   2.69437313e-10,   2.63909411e-10,
         2.62339786e-10,   2.71045386e-10,   2.65850861e-10,
         2.78162780e-10,   2.61231989e-10,   2.70109868e-10,
         2.61595375e-10,   2.59299272e-10,   2.65106316e-10,
         2.74283076e-10,   2.86861196e-10,   3.03175803e-10,
         2.58290170e-10,   3.61324845e-10,   3.39239278e-10,
         2.91296094e-10,   2.83918017e-10,   4.52002829e-10,
         2.52915179e-10,   3.13709791e-10,   3.72555078e-10,
         2.48903834e-10,   2.58089690e-10,   2.86634265e-10,
         2.60879823e-10,   2.64643448e-10,   3.03583577e-10,
         5.12385186e-10,   2.42415186e-10,   3.47677749e-10,
         2.41037177e-10,   2.91624837e-10,   2.88486833e-10,
         2.97731066e-10,   3.46537042e-10,   2.44416103e-10,
         4.29099468e-10,   4.71320607e-10,   2.97672164e-10,
         3.26787171e-10,   2.34920240e-10,   2.64792458e-10,
         2.91952218e-10,   2.47064463e-10,   2.34000456e-10,
         4.10948830e-10,   2.36520479e-10,   3.42444147e-10,
         2.76749245e-10,   2.51379106e-10,   2.40093828e-10,
         2.72602754e-10,   3.94004751e-10,   2.84796018e-10,
         3.72431030e-10,   2.23313796e-10,   3.32252341e-10,
         3.34369044e-10,   2.63230702e-10,   2.17694780e-10,
         3.25346854e-10,   2.64869219e-10,   3.51158895e-10,
         3.60872478e-10,   3.09047143e-10,   2.22308395e-10,
         2.43344334e-10,   2.16527726e-10,   2.98642975e-10,
         2.77152047e-10,   2.66161092e-10,   2.91230604e-10,
         2.37973344e-10,   2.95802884e-10,   2.78890213e-10,
         2.19485810e-10,   3.53536609e-10,   2.16716319e-10,
         2.51682560e-10,   2.04749227e-10,   4.31531575e-10,
         3.47595602e-10,   2.38112586e-10,   1.92156254e-10,
         2.46451083e-10,   2.99903096e-10,   1.90926751e-10,
         2.05652721e-10,   2.33415220e-10,   2.43209873e-10,
         1.85670073e-10,   2.02780645e-10,   1.89290313e-10,
         1.81291292e-10,   1.77940599e-10,   3.60470288e-10,
         3.28978503e-10,   1.74204497e-10,   1.95779041e-10,
         2.50524362e-10,   2.49249184e-10,   1.67522152e-10,
         1.68202192e-10,   1.82172067e-10,   1.77510490e-10,
         1.62468247e-10,   1.75426885e-10,   3.24084379e-10,
         2.21087707e-10,   1.88843987e-10,   2.57800867e-10,
         1.53483353e-10,   1.80491618e-10,   2.28820880e-10,
         2.32095332e-10,   1.90031952e-10,   1.46493968e-10,
         2.00403717e-10,   3.23811210e-10,   1.90421082e-10,
         1.45237509e-10,   1.67970046e-10,   1.49189288e-10,
         1.39748871e-10,   1.40621758e-10,   1.33316350e-10,
         2.22781676e-10,   1.31021647e-10,   2.12758988e-10,
         1.38894682e-10,   1.75219768e-10,   1.78296709e-10,
         3.67044064e-10,   2.04279379e-10,   2.11899286e-10,
         1.59322174e-10,   1.21129350e-10,   1.18003803e-10,
         1.42850831e-10,   1.33020880e-10,   1.27620814e-10,
         1.48379719e-10,   3.35008994e-10,   3.31675208e-10,
         2.49871984e-10,   1.06526186e-10,   1.57190187e-10,
         9.38688508e-11,   2.16167913e-10,   1.12548066e-10,
         1.98572296e-10,   2.12773340e-10,   3.09554965e-10,
         2.32665662e-10,   8.05365861e-11,   2.71090303e-10,
         1.60686511e-10,   1.20088934e-10,   3.23772391e-10,
         2.01129249e-10,   3.04370308e-10,   6.75862037e-11,
         7.60074235e-11,   1.55486106e-10,   2.24650749e-10,
         2.10826836e-10,   3.75354523e-10,   1.48504437e-10,
         1.65019969e-10,   7.52309342e-11,   3.59188285e-10,
         1.55801401e-10,   1.52568581e-10,   5.38230045e-11])
           sol: <scipy.interpolate.interpolate.PPoly object at 0x2ad860930d58>
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([ 0.        ,  0.003367  ,  0.00673401,  0.01010101,  0.01346801,
        0.01683502,  0.02020202,  0.02356902,  0.02693603,  0.03030303,
        0.03367003,  0.03703704,  0.04040404,  0.04377104,  0.04713805,
        0.05050505,  0.05387205,  0.05723906,  0.06060606,  0.06397306,
        0.06734007,  0.07070707,  0.07407407,  0.07744108,  0.08080808,
        0.08417508,  0.08754209,  0.09090909,  0.09427609,  0.0976431 ,
        0.1010101 ,  0.1043771 ,  0.10774411,  0.11111111,  0.11447811,
        0.11784512,  0.12121212,  0.12457912,  0.12794613,  0.13131313,
        0.13468013,  0.13804714,  0.14141414,  0.14478114,  0.14814815,
        0.15151515,  0.15488215,  0.15824916,  0.16161616,  0.16498316,
        0.16835017,  0.17171717,  0.17508418,  0.17845118,  0.18181818,
        0.18518519,  0.18855219,  0.19191919,  0.1952862 ,  0.1986532 ,
        0.2020202 ,  0.20538721,  0.20875421,  0.21212121,  0.21548822,
        0.21885522,  0.22222222,  0.22558923,  0.22895623,  0.23232323,
        0.23569024,  0.23905724,  0.24242424,  0.24579125,  0.24915825,
        0.25252525,  0.25589226,  0.25925926,  0.26262626,  0.26599327,
        0.26936027,  0.27272727,  0.27609428,  0.27946128,  0.28282828,
        0.28619529,  0.28956229,  0.29292929,  0.2962963 ,  0.2996633 ,
        0.3030303 ,  0.30639731,  0.30976431,  0.31313131,  0.31649832,
        0.31986532,  0.32323232,  0.32659933,  0.32996633,  0.33333333,
        0.33670034,  0.34006734,  0.34343434,  0.34680135,  0.35016835,
        0.35353535,  0.35690236,  0.36026936,  0.36363636,  0.36700337,
        0.37037037,  0.37373737,  0.37710438,  0.38047138,  0.38383838,
        0.38720539,  0.39057239,  0.39393939,  0.3973064 ,  0.4006734 ,
        0.4040404 ,  0.40740741,  0.41077441,  0.41414141,  0.41750842,
        0.42087542,  0.42424242,  0.42760943,  0.43097643,  0.43434343,
        0.43771044,  0.44107744,  0.44444444,  0.44781145,  0.45117845,
        0.45454545,  0.45791246,  0.46127946,  0.46464646,  0.46801347,
        0.47138047,  0.47474747,  0.47811448,  0.48148148,  0.48484848,
        0.48821549,  0.49158249,  0.49494949,  0.4983165 ,  0.5016835 ,
        0.50505051,  0.50841751,  0.51178451,  0.51515152,  0.51851852,
        0.52188552,  0.52525253,  0.52861953,  0.53198653,  0.53535354,
        0.53872054,  0.54208754,  0.54545455,  0.54882155,  0.55218855,
        0.55555556,  0.55892256,  0.56228956,  0.56565657,  0.56902357,
        0.57239057,  0.57575758,  0.57912458,  0.58249158,  0.58585859,
        0.58922559,  0.59259259,  0.5959596 ,  0.5993266 ,  0.6026936 ,
        0.60606061,  0.60942761,  0.61279461,  0.61616162,  0.61952862,
        0.62289562,  0.62626263,  0.62962963,  0.63299663,  0.63636364,
        0.63973064,  0.64309764,  0.64646465,  0.64983165,  0.65319865,
        0.65656566,  0.65993266,  0.66329966,  0.66666667,  0.67003367,
        0.67340067,  0.67676768,  0.68013468,  0.68350168,  0.68686869,
        0.69023569,  0.69360269,  0.6969697 ,  0.7003367 ,  0.7037037 ,
        0.70707071,  0.71043771,  0.71380471,  0.71717172,  0.72053872,
        0.72390572,  0.72727273,  0.73063973,  0.73400673,  0.73737374,
        0.74074074,  0.74410774,  0.74747475,  0.75084175,  0.75420875,
        0.75757576,  0.76094276,  0.76430976,  0.76767677,  0.77104377,
        0.77441077,  0.77777778,  0.78114478,  0.78451178,  0.78787879,
        0.79124579,  0.79461279,  0.7979798 ,  0.8013468 ,  0.8047138 ,
        0.80808081,  0.81144781,  0.81481481,  0.81818182,  0.82154882,
        0.82491582,  0.82828283,  0.83164983,  0.83501684,  0.83838384,
        0.84175084,  0.84511785,  0.84848485,  0.85185185,  0.85521886,
        0.85858586,  0.86195286,  0.86531987,  0.86868687,  0.87205387,
        0.87542088,  0.87878788,  0.88215488,  0.88552189,  0.88888889,
        0.89225589,  0.8956229 ,  0.8989899 ,  0.9023569 ,  0.90572391,
        0.90909091,  0.91245791,  0.91582492,  0.91919192,  0.92255892,
        0.92592593,  0.92929293,  0.93265993,  0.93602694,  0.93939394,
        0.94276094,  0.94612795,  0.94949495,  0.95286195,  0.95622896,
        0.95959596,  0.96296296,  0.96632997,  0.96969697,  0.97306397,
        0.97643098,  0.97979798,  0.98316498,  0.98653199,  0.98989899,
        0.99326599,  0.996633  ,  1.        ])
             y: array([[ 0.79388397,  0.79388847,  0.79390197,  0.79392447,  0.79395597,
         0.79399647,  0.79404598,  0.79410449,  0.794172  ,  0.79424853,
         0.79433406,  0.7944286 ,  0.79453215,  0.79464471,  0.7947663 ,
         0.7948969 ,  0.79503653,  0.79518518,  0.79534287,  0.79550958,
         0.79568534,  0.79587013,  0.79606397,  0.79626686,  0.7964788 ,
         0.7966998 ,  0.79692987,  0.797169  ,  0.79741721,  0.7976745 ,
         0.79794087,  0.79821634,  0.7985009 ,  0.79879457,  0.79909735,
         0.79940925,  0.79973028,  0.80006043,  0.80039973,  0.80074817,
         0.80110577,  0.80147253,  0.80184846,  0.80223358,  0.80262788,
         0.80303138,  0.80344409,  0.80386601,  0.80429716,  0.80473755,
         0.80518718,  0.80564606,  0.80611421,  0.80659164,  0.80707835,
         0.80757437,  0.80807969,  0.80859433,  0.8091183 ,  0.80965162,
         0.8101943 ,  0.81074634,  0.81130776,  0.81187857,  0.81245879,
         0.81304843,  0.8136475 ,  0.81425602,  0.814874  ,  0.81550144,
         0.81613838,  0.81678482,  0.81744077,  0.81810625,  0.81878128,
         0.81946586,  0.82016002,  0.82086378,  0.82157714,  0.82230012,
         0.82303274,  0.82377501,  0.82452696,  0.8252886 ,  0.82605994,
         0.826841  ,  0.8276318 ,  0.82843236,  0.82924269,  0.83006282,
         0.83089275,  0.83173252,  0.83258213,  0.83344161,  0.83431098,
         0.83519025,  0.83607944,  0.83697858,  0.83788768,  0.83880677,
         0.83973586,  0.84067497,  0.84162413,  0.84258336,  0.84355267,
         0.84453209,  0.84552164,  0.84652134,  0.84753122,  0.84855129,
         0.84958158,  0.85062211,  0.8516729 ,  0.85273397,  0.85380536,
         0.85488708,  0.85597915,  0.85708161,  0.85819447,  0.85931775,
         0.86045149,  0.86159571,  0.86275043,  0.86391567,  0.86509147,
         0.86627784,  0.86747482,  0.86868242,  0.86990068,  0.87112962,
         0.87236927,  0.87361965,  0.8748808 ,  0.87615273,  0.87743548,
         0.87872907,  0.88003353,  0.88134889,  0.88267518,  0.88401242,
         0.88536065,  0.88671989,  0.88809017,  0.88947152,  0.89086397,
         0.89226754,  0.89368228,  0.89510821,  0.89654536,  0.89799375,
         0.89945343,  0.90092442,  0.90240675,  0.90390045,  0.90540555,
         0.9069221 ,  0.90845011,  0.90998962,  0.91154066,  0.91310327,
         0.91467748,  0.91626331,  0.91786081,  0.91947001,  0.92109093,
         0.92272362,  0.92436811,  0.92602442,  0.9276926 ,  0.92937269,
         0.9310647 ,  0.93276869,  0.93448468,  0.93621271,  0.93795282,
         0.93970504,  0.9414694 ,  0.94324595,  0.94503471,  0.94683573,
         0.94864904,  0.95047469,  0.95231269,  0.9541631 ,  0.95602595,
         0.95790128,  0.95978913,  0.96168953,  0.96360252,  0.96552814,
         0.96746643,  0.96941743,  0.97138117,  0.9733577 ,  0.97534706,
         0.97734928,  0.97936441,  0.98139248,  0.98343353,  0.98548761,
         0.98755476,  0.98963501,  0.99172841,  0.993835  ,  0.99595481,
         0.9980879 ,  1.0002343 ,  1.00239405,  1.0045672 ,  1.00675379,
         1.00895385,  1.01116744,  1.0133946 ,  1.01563536,  1.01788978,
         1.02015789,  1.02243974,  1.02473537,  1.02704483,  1.02936815,
         1.03170539,  1.03405659,  1.03642179,  1.03880103,  1.04119437,
         1.04360185,  1.0460235 ,  1.04845939,  1.05090954,  1.05337402,
         1.05585286,  1.05834611,  1.06085381,  1.06337602,  1.06591277,
         1.06846412,  1.07103012,  1.0736108 ,  1.07620622,  1.07881642,
         1.08144145,  1.08408136,  1.0867362 ,  1.08940601,  1.09209084,
         1.09479074,  1.09750576,  1.10023595,  1.10298135,  1.10574202,
         1.108518  ,  1.11130934,  1.11411609,  1.1169383 ,  1.11977602,
         1.1226293 ,  1.12549819,  1.12838274,  1.13128299,  1.13419901,
         1.13713083,  1.14007851,  1.14304211,  1.14602166,  1.14901722,
         1.15202884,  1.15505658,  1.15810048,  1.1611606 ,  1.16423698,
         1.16732967,  1.17043874,  1.17356423,  1.17670619,  1.17986467,
         1.18303973,  1.18623141,  1.18943978,  1.19266488,  1.19590676,
         1.19916548,  1.20244108,  1.20573363,  1.20904318,  1.21236977,
         1.21571346,  1.2190743 ,  1.22245235,  1.22584765,  1.22926027,
         1.23269025,  1.23613766,  1.23960253,  1.24308492,  1.2465849 ,
         1.25010251,  1.2536378 ,  1.25719083]])
            yp: array([[ 0.        ,  0.00267302,  0.0053461 ,  0.0080193 ,  0.01069269,
         0.01336631,  0.01604024,  0.01871453,  0.02138925,  0.02406445,
         0.0267402 ,  0.02941655,  0.03209358,  0.03477132,  0.03744986,
         0.04012924,  0.04280954,  0.0454908 ,  0.04817309,  0.05085648,
         0.05354102,  0.05622677,  0.05891379,  0.06160215,  0.0642919 ,
         0.06698311,  0.06967583,  0.07237013,  0.07506607,  0.0777637 ,
         0.0804631 ,  0.08316431,  0.08586741,  0.08857244,  0.09127948,
         0.09398858,  0.0966998 ,  0.09941321,  0.10212887,  0.10484683,
         0.10756715,  0.11028991,  0.11301515,  0.11574295,  0.11847335,
         0.12120642,  0.12394223,  0.12668083,  0.12942228,  0.13216665,
         0.134914  ,  0.13766438,  0.14041786,  0.1431745 ,  0.14593436,
         0.1486975 ,  0.15146398,  0.15423387,  0.15700722,  0.1597841 ,
         0.16256456,  0.16534867,  0.16813649,  0.17092808,  0.1737235 ,
         0.17652281,  0.17932607,  0.18213335,  0.18494471,  0.1877602 ,
         0.1905799 ,  0.19340385,  0.19623212,  0.19906478,  0.20190187,
         0.20474348,  0.20758965,  0.21044044,  0.21329593,  0.21615617,
         0.21902122,  0.22189114,  0.22476599,  0.22764585,  0.23053076,
         0.23342079,  0.236316  ,  0.23921645,  0.2421222 ,  0.24503332,
         0.24794987,  0.2508719 ,  0.25379948,  0.25673268,  0.25967155,
         0.26261615,  0.26556655,  0.2685228 ,  0.27148497,  0.27445313,
         0.27742732,  0.28040762,  0.28339409,  0.28638678,  0.28938576,
         0.29239109,  0.29540283,  0.29842105,  0.3014458 ,  0.30447715,
         0.30751515,  0.31055988,  0.31361139,  0.31666974,  0.31973499,
         0.32280722,  0.32588647,  0.32897281,  0.3320663 ,  0.33516701,
         0.33827498,  0.3413903 ,  0.34451301,  0.34764319,  0.35078088,
         0.35392616,  0.35707908,  0.3602397 ,  0.3634081 ,  0.36658432,
         0.36976843,  0.37296049,  0.37616057,  0.37936872,  0.382585  ,
         0.38580948,  0.38904223,  0.39228329,  0.39553273,  0.39879061,
         0.402057  ,  0.40533195,  0.40861553,  0.4119078 ,  0.41520881,
         0.41851863,  0.42183733,  0.42516495,  0.42850157,  0.43184723,
         0.43520202,  0.43856597,  0.44193917,  0.44532166,  0.4487135 ,
         0.45211476,  0.45552551,  0.45894578,  0.46237566,  0.4658152 ,
         0.46926446,  0.47272349,  0.47619237,  0.47967114,  0.48315988,
         0.48665863,  0.49016747,  0.49368644,  0.49721562,  0.50075505,
         0.5043048 ,  0.50786493,  0.5114355 ,  0.51501656,  0.51860818,
         0.52221041,  0.52582331,  0.52944695,  0.53308138,  0.53672666,
         0.54038285,  0.54405001,  0.54772819,  0.55141745,  0.55511786,
         0.55882946,  0.56255232,  0.5662865 ,  0.57003205,  0.57378903,
         0.5775575 ,  0.58133751,  0.58512912,  0.58893239,  0.59274738,
         0.59657414,  0.60041272,  0.60426319,  0.6081256 ,  0.61200001,
         0.61588646,  0.61978503,  0.62369576,  0.6276187 ,  0.63155392,
         0.63550147,  0.6394614 ,  0.64343376,  0.64741862,  0.65141602,
         0.65542602,  0.65944867,  0.66348403,  0.66753215,  0.67159308,
         0.67566687,  0.67975358,  0.68385327,  0.68796597,  0.69209174,
         0.69623064,  0.70038272,  0.70454802,  0.7087266 ,  0.7129185 ,
         0.71712379,  0.7213425 ,  0.72557469,  0.72982041,  0.7340797 ,
         0.73835262,  0.74263921,  0.74693953,  0.75125361,  0.75558151,
         0.75992327,  0.76427895,  0.76864858,  0.77303222,  0.7774299 ,
         0.78184168,  0.7862676 ,  0.79070771,  0.79516204,  0.79963065,
         0.80411358,  0.80861086,  0.81312256,  0.81764869,  0.82218932,
         0.82674447,  0.8313142 ,  0.83589854,  0.84049753,  0.84511122,
         0.84973964,  0.85438283,  0.85904083,  0.86371368,  0.86840142,
         0.87310408,  0.8778217 ,  0.88255432,  0.88730198,  0.89206471,
         0.89684254,  0.90163551,  0.90644365,  0.911267  ,  0.91610559,
         0.92095945,  0.92582862,  0.93071312,  0.93561298,  0.94052825,
         0.94545894,  0.95040508,  0.95536671,  0.96034386,  0.96533654,
         0.97034479,  0.97536863,  0.98040809,  0.98546319,  0.99053396,
         0.99562042,  1.0007226 ,  1.00584051,  1.01097418,  1.01612363,
         1.02128888,  1.02646995,  1.03166686,  1.03687962,  1.04210827,
         1.0473528 ,  1.05261324,  1.0578896 ]])
```

As you can see, y is very far from the boundary conditions of `y(x=0) = y(x=1) = 1`.

Comment: could you provide a sample code to start with and see the error? the boundary condition is a callable function according to the document, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `bc` is a callable function of dimension `n`, i.e. the number of equations. I have `n=1` equations but I want it to be bound on both sides, at `x=0` and also at `x=1`.

Comment: Also, there seems to be no tolerance on the violation of the boundary conditions. So the solutions I'm getting are very far from my specified boundary.

Comment: @Mehdi I added a MWE

Comment: If you specify two boundary conditions y(0)=1 and y(1)=1 for a first order ODE, then in general the problem is overdetermined and *there is no solution*.  If you specify just the initial condition y(0)=y0, you have a first order initial value problem.  In fact, in this case, you can derive the exact solution: y(x) = y0*exp(-cos(x)).

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser, you're right, I forgot about that. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: OK, it is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify two boundary conditions y(0)=1 and y(1)=1 for a first order ODE, then in general the problem is overdetermined and *there is no solution*. If you specify just the initial condition y(0)=y0, you have a first order initial value problem. In fact, in this case, you can derive the exact solution: y(x) = y0*exp(-cos(x)).

Comment: Suppose [one is trying to create an SIR model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924050/adapting-initial-value-problem-to-boundary-value-problem-using-scipy-integrate-s), for which one has two boundary conditions but for more than one y-component. This way, the `y` arg accepted by boundary condition function `bc` looks like `y=[dy1/dt, dy2/dt, dy3/dt]` where `y1=S`, `y2=I`, `y3=R`. The boundary conditions are taken as `dyi/dt[0] = some number, dyi/dt[-1] = another number` for `i=1,2,3`. Is the problem still over-determined? If not, how can one use `solve_bvp` with more than one `bc` func?

Comment: @allthemikeysaretaken: *"The boundary conditions are taken as dyi/dt[0] = some number, dyi/dt[-1] = another number for i=1,2,3. Is the problem still over-determined?"*  That imposes 6 conditions on your 3-d system, so yes, the problem would be overdetermined, even if the two parameters in the system are considered variables.  Lutz Lehmann summarized the issue in the comments to your question.